# how can I convert values to a meaning separated with a colon (double point)

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(df = structure(c(10L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 
8L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("-1:-1:2", "-1:2:-1", "-1:2:2", "1:01:01", 
"1:1(2):1", "1(1)|1(2):1(1)|1(2):1(1)|1(2)", "1(1)|1(2):2:2", 
"2:-1:-1", "2:-1:2", "2:02:02"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

I want to expend it to words as I define. I want to have as many columns as the number of double points , for example here we have three : so we will add 3 columns after the df. Then we fill it up with words

```
2 = Homo
-1 = No
1= Het
1(1)= Het1 
1(2)= Het2
```

So an expected output looks like below.

```
2:02:02 Homo    Homo    Homo
2:-1:-1 Homo    No  No
-1:2:-1 No  Homo    No
2:-1:-1 Homo    No  No
1(1)|1(2):2:2   Het1 Het2   Homo    Homo
1(1)|1(2):2:2   Het1 Het2   Homo    Homo
2:02:02 Homo    Homo    Homo
2:-1:-1 Homo    No  No
-1:2:2  No  Homo    Homo
2:02:02 Homo    Homo    Homo
2:02:02 Homo    Homo    Homo
2:-1:2  Homo    No  Homo
2:-1:2  Homo    No  Homo
-1:-1:2 No  No  Homo
-1:-1:2 No  No  Homo
-1:2:2  No  Homo    Homo
-1:-1:2 No  No  Homo
1:1(2):1    Het Het2    Het
1:1(2):1    Het Het3    Het
1:01:01 Het Het Het
2:02:02 Homo    Homo    Homo
2:-1:-1 Homo    No  No
-1:-1:2 No  No  Homo
-1:-1:2 No  No  Homo
-1:2:-1 No  Homo    No
1(1)|1(2):1(1)|1(2):1(1)|1(2)   Het1 Het2   Het1 Het2   Het1 Het2
```

Comment: By "double points" do you mean a colon? Is this a regional term? Never heard it in the US

Comment: @camille In Portugal it is *"dois pontos"*, meaning *"two points"*.

Comment: @Camille I meant :

Comment: Will `02` and `2` matches to the same string?

Comment: @akrun Yes 02 and 2 are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the result is exactly what you need, but maybe this could help.
I think also maybe it's not the most efficient and beautiful solution, but it can be a starting point.

However, I called `dats` your data:

```
head(dats)
                              df
1                        2:02:02
2                        2:-1:-1
3                        -1:2:-1
4                        2:-1:-1
5                  1(1)|1(2):2:2
6                  1(1)|1(2):2:2
```

And I created a mapping `data.frame`:

```
mapping
    id value
1    2  Homo
2   -1    No
3    1   Het
4 1(1)  Het1
5 1(2)  Het2
```

First, I splitted with `stringr::str_split_fixed()` the double points:

```
library(stringr)
double_point <- as.data.frame.matrix(str_split_fixed(dats$df, ":", 3))
```

Now we have to separate for each column, the values by `|`:

```
listed <- list() # empty list 
for (i in (1:ncol(double_point))){
  listed[[i]] <- (double_point[,i])
  listed[[i]] <- str_split_fixed(listed[[i]], "\\|", 2)
}

# put as data frame
df_ <- do.call(cbind, listed)

# this is going to help in the future
df_1 <- df_

# result till now:
head(df_1)
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "2"    ""     "02" ""   "02" ""  
[2,] "2"    ""     "-1" ""   "-1" ""  
[3,] "-1"   ""     "2"  ""   "-1" ""  
[4,] "2"    ""     "-1" ""   "-1" ""  
[5,] "1(1)" "1(2)" "2"  ""   "2"  ""  
[6,] "1(1)" "1(2)" "2"  ""   "2"  ""
```

Now we have to replace the values with the mapping, and bind them with the original data splitted (in this case):

```
listed <- list()

for (i in (1:ncol(df_))){
  df_[,i] <-  gsub("0","",df_[,i])
  listed[[i]] <- mapping[match(df_[,i], mapping$id), 2, drop=F]
}

df_final <- cbind(df_1,do.call(cbind, listed))
head(df_final)
       1    2  3 4  5 6 value value value value value value
1      2      02   02    Homo  <NA>  Homo  <NA>  Homo  <NA>
1.1    2      -1   -1    Homo  <NA>    No  <NA>    No  <NA>
2     -1       2   -1      No  <NA>  Homo  <NA>    No  <NA>
1.2    2      -1   -1    Homo  <NA>    No  <NA>    No  <NA>
4   1(1) 1(2)  2    2    Het1  Het2  Homo  <NA>  Homo  <NA>
4.1 1(1) 1(2)  2    2    Het1  Het2  Homo  <NA>  Homo  <NA>
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Here the mapping `dput()` and `str()`:

```
dput(mapping)
structure(list(id = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("-1", 
"1", "1(1)", "1(2)", "2"), class = "factor"), value = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Het", "Het1", "Het2", "Homo", "No"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))

str(mapping)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ id   : Factor w/ 5 levels "-1","1","1(1)",..: 5 1 2 3 4
 $ value: Factor w/ 5 levels "Het","Het1","Het2",..: 4 5 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks, your code does not print for 1(1) or 1(2) . can you please tell me the str of mapping ?

Comment: Hi,posted the edit. It seems that in the last rows of the last output, it prints for the cases you mention.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly define all the possible values in `num2words` data frame and then run the following

```
df<- structure(list(df = structure(c(10L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 
                                     8L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("-1:-1:2", "-1:2:-1", "-1:2:2", "1:01:01", 
                                                                 "1:1(2):1", "1(1)|1(2):1(1)|1(2):1(1)|1(2)", "1(1)|1(2):2:2", 
                                                                 "2:-1:-1", "2:-1:2", "2:02:02"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                          -26L))
num2words <- read.table(text = "
                        num word
                        2 Homo
                        02  Homo
                        -1  No
                        1 Het
                        01  Het                        
                        1(1)  Het1
                        1(2)  Het2
                        1(1)|1(2) Het1-Het2
                        1(2)|1(1) Het2-Het1
                        ", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

lst=lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {
  split.nums <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(df[x,]), ":"))
  num2words$word[match(split.nums, num2words$num)]
})

new.df=cbind(df, do.call(rbind, lst))

> new.df

                              df         1         2         3
1                        2:02:02      Homo      Homo      Homo
2                        2:-1:-1      Homo        No        No
3                        -1:2:-1        No      Homo        No
4                        2:-1:-1      Homo        No        No
5                  1(1)|1(2):2:2 Het1-Het2      Homo      Homo
6                  1(1)|1(2):2:2 Het1-Het2      Homo      Homo
7                        2:02:02      Homo      Homo      Homo
8                        2:-1:-1      Homo        No        No
9                         -1:2:2        No      Homo      Homo
10                       2:02:02      Homo      Homo      Homo
11                       2:02:02      Homo      Homo      Homo
12                        2:-1:2      Homo        No      Homo
13                        2:-1:2      Homo        No      Homo
14                       -1:-1:2        No        No      Homo
15                       -1:-1:2        No        No      Homo
16                        -1:2:2        No      Homo      Homo
17                       -1:-1:2        No        No      Homo
18                      1:1(2):1       Het      Het2       Het
19                      1:1(2):1       Het      Het2       Het
20                       1:01:01       Het       Het       Het
21                       2:02:02      Homo      Homo      Homo
22                       2:-1:-1      Homo        No        No
23                       -1:-1:2        No        No      Homo
24                       -1:-1:2        No        No      Homo
25                       -1:2:-1        No      Homo        No
26 1(1)|1(2):1(1)|1(2):1(1)|1(2) Het1-Het2 Het1-Het2 Het1-Het2
```